# Run Tests Unavailable in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Not strictly a programming question, but definately programming related.

The option to run tests in Visual Studio is greyed out for some reason. I've just started a File | new MVC Application, using VS2008pro.

[alt text http://www.olympianbot.co.uk/images/greyed-tests.jpg](http://www.olympianbot.co.uk/images/greyed-tests.jpg)

Any idea what causes this / how to resolve it?

Comment: A few questions... Can you see the tests in TestView ??
Is your vsmdi file up to date ?
Are you tests marked as enabled (add enabled column in TestView to check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio recognizes test projects by a special GUID. If there's a project with the GUID : `FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC`, VS will automatically load tests from it. So make sure that in the .csproj of your test project you have the correct GUID:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```